# Quarkus build failure: Interceptor has no bindings: org.jboss.solder.exception.control.ExceptionHandledInterceptor

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm trying to port a small corporate (mutli module) RESTEasy JAX-RS application to Quarkus, but I'm hitting the error below. I checked the code of the application itself, but I cannot find any references to the Solder's exception handling, so I suspect it's coming from the external dependencies (there are a number of corporate ones over which I have no control). I searched on the Internet for this particualr error, hoping it's just a Quarkus dependency or configuration that I missed, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Or maybe it's not yet implementred in Quarkus.

Any help appreciated.

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL)`

Java: `OpenJDK 11.0.8`

Command: `./mvnw clean install -DskipTests`

Error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.9.0.Final:build (default) on project <REDACTED>: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#registerBeans threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: Interceptor has no bindings: org.jboss.solder.exception.control.ExceptionHandledInterceptor
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Interceptors.createInterceptor(Interceptors.java:44)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.findInterceptors(BeanDeployment.java:1052)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.registerBeans(BeanDeployment.java:220)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.registerBeans(BeanProcessor.java:115)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.registerBeans(ArcProcessor.java:381)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:936)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :<REDACTED>
```

Update 18/11/2020:
The dependency itself is coming from a corporate SDK jar over which I have no control:

```
[INFO] +- com.<REDACTED>.sdk:sdk-context-core-non-cdi:jar:<REDACTED>:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.<REDACTED>.sdk:sdk-services-core:jar:<REDACTED>:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.solder:solder-impl:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jboss.solder:solder-api:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.jboss.solder:solder-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:provided
```

Thanks,
Emil

Comment: This seems to be a Seam class, most likely added by a dependency (or transitive dependency in your project). Quarkus does not integrate with Seam, so that causes the error.  Are you able to check the dependencies and try to remove the problematic dependency? You can use `mvn dependency:tree` and check where the dependency is coming from.

Comment: @RobertoCortez thanks a lot for the reply, it's giving me some useful pointers.

Comment: The dependency itself is coming from a corporate SDK jar over which I have no control (I updated the issue description with it). So my only option is to see if I can remove/replace the dependency in the application code itself. More that likely Quarkus would never integrate with Seam, as  this framework stop being developed in 2012.

Comment: Well you can exclude that specific dependency. I'm guessing you are including `sdk-context-core-non-cdi`. In the dependency declaration, just add an exclusion to `org.jboss.solder:solder-impl:jar`: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions

Comment: @RobertoCortez excluding `org.jboss.solder:solder-impl` in the pom did the trick (although I wonder if there might be a potential problem when running in AWS Lambda), this error is done. Now I hit other dependency errors, but I'll create a new post for them.

Answer (score 0):

As @RobertoCortez suggested, excluding org.jboss.solder:solder-impl in the pom solved the error: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions

There is a possibility however that, once deployed, the application might produce exceptions related to the missing library.